# Which pages from the sitemap are not indexed by Google?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap

I have a sitemap file that has been submitted to Google, and has been processed, according to Google Webmaster Tools.

As per GWT for 2013-05-31, 8255 web-pages are submitted, but only 8209 are indexed.

Which 46 of the 8255 pages are not indexed?

Answer (score 2):

[ThompsonPaul wrote on moz.com about figuring out which pages are not indexed](http://moz.com/community/q/how-to-determine-which-pages-are-not-indexed#reply_125001).  Here is a summary of what he has to say:

- There is no easy way or single tool to get this data for you
- You can get a partial list of which pages are indexed using the a `site:` search on Google.  You can [use a bookmarklet](http://www.onlinesales.co.uk/seo/bookmarklet/serps.php) grab the search results into a list more easily.
- Remove these URLs that you know are indexed from the list of pages in your sitemap.  You are left with a list of potentially not indexed URLs.
- The remaining URLs can be checked individually to see if they are indexed.

Clearly this is a manual and time consuming task that isn't going to work well if you site has more than thousands of pages.