# Does Google Webmaster Tools allow me to find out which pages are indexed?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, xml-sitemap

If I'd go to Crawl -> Sitemaps section there will be a list of sitemaps with the number of total pages in each one and the number of indexed pages indicated.

However I didn't see any way of finding out which pages of the sitemap actually indexed.

Of course I could use Google search with keyword "site:mysite.com" to have a look at the list of indexed pages but there will be no correlation to the sitemap.  I will not be able to do any analysis of reasons the pages are not in index.

Comment: We have another very similar question: [Which pages from the sitemap are not indexed by Google?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49099/which-pages-from-the-sitemap-are-not-indexed-by-google)

Answer (score 1):

There is no list of "indexed pages" anywhere in Google Webmaster Tools.  GWT will give you the *count* of indexed pages, but no list.

I believe that the only way you can get a list of pages that Google has indexed it so search on Google for `site:example.com` then page through the search results.  Even then, it is not a *complete* list of indexed pages.  Google purposely makes `site:` results somewhat inaccurate.

[ThompsonPaul wrote on moz.com about figuring out which pages are not indexed](http://moz.com/community/q/how-to-determine-which-pages-are-not-indexed#reply_125001).  His post is worth reading because he suggests more advanced techniques such as a bookmarklet that makes copying the pages out of the results pages easier.