# How do I tell which pages of my website are not indexed in Google?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index

Is there any way to find non-indexed pages of my website?

I tried searching on-line for this answer but couldn't find the exact solution for how to find the non-indexed pages in Google.

If I were able to find them, I could "fetch as Google" and request that Google index the pages.   My goal would be to make sure all the pages are indexed in Google.

Comment: Have you tried using Google Webmaster Tools - https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/? Once you setup your website in there, it will tell what is indexed. You should then be able to compute what isn't.

Comment: See also: [Does Google Webmaster Tools allow me to find out which pages are indexed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61710/does-google-webmaster-tools-allow-me-to-find-out-which-pages-are-indexed)

Comment: On Quora: [How can i find out the pages that are not indexed by google?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-i-find-out-the-pages-that-are-not-indexed-by-google)

Answer (score 4):

Yes... but your site should be fully crawl-able. You can compare your sitemap and index count. In Google Search Console it will say Submitted X Url's / Indexed X Url's. So if the number is lower or greater then you know some URLS are missing in the index or more.

Additionally you can use `site:example.com` to find out what is indexed but ut is only sample data (a small portion) but as far as exporting or comparing from a list, no Google doesn't support that...

Solve the issue by making sure your website is crawl-able. If it is, then building your reputation with Google, that way it will increase your crawl duration and return rate, therefore increasing the amount of time it takes to index your pages.

Comment: Sure - It is useful , but how do I know about the exact urls which is not indexed by Google. ??
If I know the exact Urls - then I can fetch only those pages from Google Webmaster and make them indexed 100/100 ??

Comment: Your suppose compare your site map with the index amount, it displays this number when you submit the sitemap.

Comment: Yes off-course - I see how many pages are not indexed in Google. But the main thing I am not able to find which pages are not indexed..

Comment: You can't... Google and Bing will only notify you when page can't be indexed that that discovers whcih is blocked via robots.txt or another. So, everything else it finds will be indexed... your asking Google to tell you pages that are not indexed before it discovers them, it makes no sense. So if Google discovers them, it indexes them... it doesn't discover them and not index them... unless something is blocking it or if the page is low quality and doesn't fit their guidelines.